# Is it okay to re-voice and use another persons MIDI file?

Tags: midi, gameaudio, copyright

If I download a MIDI file and change the instrumental voicing via Synthesia to use it in my game - Is that considered a copyright infringement?

Comment: Voting to close as this question is related to copyrights law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be, yes. The only way you'd be legally allowed to manipulate or change someone else's MIDI is if they gave you permission to do so.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on whether the copyright allows for that. If it's one of the Creative Commons licenses, then it's probably okay. If it's the critical `All Rights Reserved`, then it's probably not.